# Query to retrieve values of similar primary keys

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with two columns which looks like this:

```
+-----------+--------+
| Mobile_id | Person |
+-----------+--------+
| ME_02_05  | John   |
| ME-02 05  | Barry1 |
| 02-05     | John   |
| ME 03-02  | James  | 
+-----------+--------+
```

I want to retrieve all persons whose `Mobile_id` contains integers (02 05). It can be seen that there are different combinations of `02 05` in the table such as ME_02_05, ME-02 05 and 02-05.

Can anyone please tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Person FROM Persons WHERE Mobile_Id LIKE "%02%05"
```

should work.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Person FROM t1 WHERE Mobile_id REGEXP '02[-_ ]05'
```

This selects each `Person` entry that has `02` followed by dash, underscore, or space followed by `05`.